# Ionic 3 Template parse errors: 'add-thought' is not a known element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building an app using Ionic v3 and have created a custom component for good practice, so that I may include it in other pages easily.

The error is as follows:

```
Template parse errors:
'add-thought' is not a known element:
1. If 'add-thought' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'add-thought' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
<ion-content padding>

    [ERROR ->]<add-thought></add-thought>

    <div id="thoughts">
"): ng:///AppModule/ThoughtsPage.html@32:4
```

The relevant files are as follows:

> src\pages\thoughts\thoughts.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Thoughts</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
    <add-thought></add-thought>
    <div id="thoughts"></div>
</ion-content>
```

> src\pages\thoughts\thoughts.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ThoughtsPage } from './thoughts';
import { AddThoughtModule } from '../../components/add-thought/add-thought.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ThoughtsPage,
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(ThoughtsPage),
        AddThoughtModule
    ]
})
export class ThoughtsPageModule {}
```

> src\components\add-thought\add-thought.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ThoughtsProvider } from '../../providers/thoughts/thoughts';
import '../../models/thoughts/thoughts';

@Component({
    providers: [ThoughtsProvider],
    selector: 'add-thought',
    templateUrl: 'add-thought.html'
})
export class AddThoughtComponent {}
```

> src\components\add-thought\add-thought.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { AddThoughtComponent } from './add-thought';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AddThoughtComponent],
    imports: [],
    exports: [AddThoughtComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AddThoughtModule {}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have included the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` as requested to suppress the message. I have also tried importing the generated `components.module.ts` file globally and locally to the page. Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
By adding `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to `app.module.ts` I no longer see the error message, but the component isn't displaying either. Here's a StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-o9fbnw

Comment: create stackblitz ??

Comment: @UnluckyAj Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-o9fbnw

Answer (score 0):

Add your component to the `app.module`. I forked your work [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-thought-compoennt?file=app/app.module.ts)